403 Forbidden Error on NextAuth Credentials Callback
I'm using NextAuth.js "next-auth": "^4.24.8" for authentication in my Next.js application, and I'm encountering a 403 Forbidden error when trying to log in with credentials. Here are the details of my setup and the error:
Request Details:

Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/credentials
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

enter image description here
Here’s the relevant part of my NextAuth configuration:
import axios from "axios";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ?? "",
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ?? "",
    }),
    Credentials({
      name: "credentials",
      type: "credentials",
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const { email, password } = credentials as {
            email: string;
            password: string;
          };

          const res = await axios.post(
            `${process.env.API_BASE_URL}/auth/login`,
            {
              email,
              password,
            },
            { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }
          );
          const user = await res.data;

          if (user) {
            return Promise.resolve(user);
          }
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
        } catch (error) {
          return Promise.reject(null);
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.user = user;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session }) {
      // Session handling code...
    },
    async signIn({ profile }) {
      return profile;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

Additional Information:
I have verified that the API endpoint ${process.env.API_BASE_URL}/auth/login is functioning correctly, and it returns a valid user object when provided with correct credentials.
The user object returned is not empty, and I’m able to access the necessary fields.
I have set the necessary environment variables for Google authentication.
Questions:
What could be causing the 403 Forbidden error on the credentials callback?
Are there any specific configurations in NextAuth.js that I might be missing that could lead to this issue?
Thank you for your help!
